# Multiple authentication providers in Symfony 2 for a single firewall

Tags: php, symfony, session, authentication

I have a Symfony 2.7.6 project with custom Simple Form authentication provider and support for **remember me** functionality as well as **impersonalization** feature. Everything works as expected.

However, I want to introduce another authentication provider that will allow requests regardless of session state using two HTTP headers for authentication (e.g. `API-Client-Id` and `API-Client-Token`) for third-party applications.

I've created a Simple Pre-Auth authentication provider that validates these header fields and creates authentication token with empty User instance on success.

However, it looks like Symfony is trying to remember those API authentications using session, so I'm getting the following error on the second request: "*You cannot refresh a user from the EntityUserProvider that does not contain an identifier. The user object has to be serialized with its own identifier mapped by Doctrine.*".

I can set `stateless: true` flag in my firewall configuration to disable session support, but it will disable it for both auth providers.

SO, how do I preserve existing functionality with my Simple Form authenticator and yet create another layer of authentication to be used for single stateless API requests?

I'm not sure if my approach is conceptually correct. I will gladly accept any suggestions and will provide any relevant information on first request.

Here's my `security.yml` config:

```yaml
security:
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: app.login
                check_path: app.session.sign_in
                username_parameter: username
                password_parameter: password
                success_handler: app.security.login_handler
                failure_handler: app.security.login_handler
                require_previous_session: false
            logout:
                path: app.session.sign_out
                invalidate_session: false
                success_handler: app.security.logout_success_handler
            # Simple form auth provider
            simple_form:
                authenticator: app.security.authenticator.out_service
            # Token provider
            simple_preauth:
                authenticator: app.security.authenticator.api_client               
            remember_me:
                name: "%app.session.remember_me.name%"
                key: "%secret%"
                lifetime: 1209600 # 14 days
                path: /
                domain: ~
                always_remember_me: true
            switch_user: { role: ROLE_ADMIN }

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login,                        roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/recover-password,             roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: /,                              roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED  }

    providers:
        main:
            entity:
                class: App\AppBundle\Model\User
                property: id
    encoders:
        App\AppBundle\Model\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ACTIVE]
        ROLE_API_CLIENT: ~
        ROLE_USER: ~
        ROLE_ACTIVE: ~
```

**ApiClientAuthenticator.php**:

```php
<?php

namespace App\AppBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\PreAuthenticatedToken;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use App\AppBundle\Model\User;


class ApiClientAuthenticator implements SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface
{
    /** @var  LoggerInterface */
    protected $logger;

    /** @var  array */
    protected $clients;


    /**
     * @param array $clients
     */
    public function __construct(array $clients)
    {
        $this->clients = $clients;
    }    

    public function createToken(Request $request, $providerKey)
    {    
        $clientId = $request->headers->get('Api-Client-Id');
        $clientSecret = $request->headers->get('Api-Client-Secret');

        if (!$clientId || !$clientSecret) {
            return null;
        }

        return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
            'anon.',
            [$clientId, $clientSecret],
            $providerKey
        );
    }

    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        list ($clientId, $clientSecret) = $token->getCredentials();    

        $foundClient = null;
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($client['id'] == $clientId) {
                if ($client['secret'] == $clientSecret) {
                    $foundClient = $client;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!$foundClient) {
            throw new AuthenticationException;
        }

        $user = new User;
        $user->setApiClient(true);
        return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
            $user,
            $foundClient,
            $providerKey,
            ['ROLE_API_CLIENT']
        );
    }

    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return ($token instanceof PreAuthenticatedToken && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey);
    }    
}
```